# How can I make text in a paragraph stay at the bottom of a div without having any space below?

Tags: html, css

I want this text along with its border to stay at the bottom of the body element. I also want to place the text at the borderline of the div.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Bungee';
  font-size: 5em;
}

p {
  border: solid 8px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide an illustration of the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

2 ways:

1. Add margin-bottom:0 to 'p' element like fixed below
2. Use `<div>` instead of `<p>` without any styling.

Clarification: paragraph tag has automatic styling causing to space in your case. It may vary in different browsers/versions.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Bungee';
  font-size: 5em;
}

p {
  border: solid 8px;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, we do, because your solution doesn't seem to meet the specifications now that we can see it. That may explain the downvote.